# Import override for latitude and longitude

Tags: import, geocoding

I'm in the process of importing latitude and longitude information for contacts.  This process is straightforward but I don't see an option to upload an option to turn on 'Override automatic geocoding'.  What's the best way to turn on this option for all of these contacts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [API csv extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport). The field is called manual_geo_code and is available via the API (updated based on Jon's comment)

Comment: The field is called `manual_geo_code` and is available via the API, so this is a good option.  However, it's difficult to tell how easy this would be without seeing the CSV file.  Reason being, the `manual_geo_code` field is set on the address - so there would need to be an easy way to match the address to the contact by its ID from the CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for information. The field name is incredibly useful and I'll be able to make that work from here.